# Application unresponsive - Works Locally - Not on Deploy to EY

Tags: ruby, engineyard

I have a Ruby on Rails application that works locally using Trinidad Server and Jruby 1.6.5 (ruby 1.9.2)

However when I deploy to Engine Yard the application is unresponsive. I can make no connections to it at all. And the odd thing is that the deploy does not error and there are no errors in the production log either. Everything on the dashboard looks fine.

Without anything in log/production.log - where should I start debugging the app?

Comment: 1. Can you run the app in production mode on your machine? 2. Shouldn't you be asking EY support?